# How to stop Gnome from reordering keyboard layouts?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, keyboard-layout

I am using 3 keyboard layouts (to be exact: English, [LaTeX Table](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/ibus-table-latex), Russian). On Unity, when I pressed my "next layout" keybinding, layouts whould only be smitched in the order set in the settings window (English - Latex - Russian - English again...).

On Gnome, the story is completely different: it looks like it switches them in order of usage, like this:

1. Was on Russian, switched to English.
2. Press keybinding -- back to Russian.
3. Press again -- back to English.
4. Press twice in a row -- Latex!
5. Press once more -- English.
6. Once more -- Latex!
7. Twice -- Russian.
8. Once more -- back to Latex.

If you have only two layouts you will never see a difference.

It's pretty obvious to me that these reorderings require some logic to be implemented, but I would like to turn that off and "freeze" the order. Is there a way, though?